# Solving system of 2nd order partial differential equations in 1D

Tags: differential-equations, physical-constants

I am attempting solve a system of three partial differential equations in 1D, to obtain values of `G(x,t)`, `X(x,t)` and `Y(x,t)`. I was using the guidance of this post: [Solving system of differential equations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/154983/solving-system-of-differential-equations).

In 3D these equations look like this:

[image]

I have simplified to 1D and left out the $\chi$ function. Most of the values in the 3 equations are constants. Here is my attempt to solve them:

```
GEqns = {G'[x, t] == DG*G''[x] - (kn1 + kp2)*G[x] + kn2*X[x] + kp1*A, 
  Constants -> {DG, kn1, kp2, kn2, kp1, A}}

XEqns = {X'[x, t] == 
   DX*X''[x] + kp2*G[x] - (kn2 + kp3*B + kp5)*X[x] + kn3*Z*Y[x] - 
    kn4*X^3 + kp4*X[x]^2*Y[x] + kn5*Omega, 
  Constants -> {DX, kp2, kn2, kp3, B, kp5, kn3, Z, kn4, kp4, kp5, 
    Omega}}

YEqns = {Y'[x, t] == 
   DY*Y''[x] + kp3*B*X[x] - kn3*Z*Y[x] + kn4*X[x]^3 - 
    kp4*X[x]^2*Y[x], Constants -> {DY, kp3, B, kn3, Z, kn4, kp4}}

ResultXYG = 
 DSolve[Flatten[{GEqns, XEqns, YEqns}], {G[x, t], Y[x, t], X[x, t]}, 
    t] // FullSimplify // Flatten
```

I get the error message:

[image]

Can anyone give advise where I am going wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: for starters, dont use underscores.

Comment: Thanks I'll update it. Also, I think I need Y[x] instead of Y etc.

Comment: What is your intention using `Constants->...` in the definition of equations??

Comment: I wanted indicate that these were constants without values, so Mathematica would know they are not variables. Is there another way of doing that correctly without `Constants->` ?

Comment: Eliminate the "Constants->.." . Further, all function must have the same arguments. And all arguments (x,t) must be specified as last element of DSolve.

Comment: I strongly doubt that Mathematica will be able to find a general solution for these equations, even in 1D.  You will probably need to use `NDSolve`, which will require you to provide a set of initial conditions and boundary conditions for your functions, as well as specific numerical values for all of your constants.

Comment: Further to @DanielHuber's point, here's how to correctly provide your first equation to Mathematica:  `D[G[x, t], t] == DG*D[G[x, t], {x, 2}] - (kn1 + kp2)*G[x, t] + kn2*X[x, t] + kp1*A` Note the use of the `D` operator to specify the derivatives, and the fact that all functions of `x` and `t` are specified to have those arguments.

Comment: Thank you @Michael Seifert, that's very helpful.